# Sencha Grid Exporter fails when exporting to CSV or any other type other than xlsx?

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic, exporter

I am using Sencha Grid Exporter plugin, while it works perfectly fine when exported to Excel, I cant get it to export to CSV or any other types from my app.

It works fine as listed on the KitchenSink example.

[KitchenSink Exporter Example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#grid-exporter)

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.Exporter.html

```
Ext.getCmp('grid').saveDocumentAs({    
         type: 'csv',  // What other possible values can go here
         title: globals.reportName,
         fileName: 'myExport.csv'
});
```

Comes with an error as below:

```
Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: exporter.CSV
at Ext.Inventory.instantiateByAlias (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:13520)
at Ext.Factory.create (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:23199)
at constructor.getExporter (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:204593)
at constructor.saveDocumentAs (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:204520)
at constructor.saveDocumentAs (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:5355)
at constructor.onMenuitemClick (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:255332)
at constructor.fire (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:19281)
at constructor.doFireEvent (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:20248)
at constructor.doFireEvent (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:65488)
at constructor.prototype.doFireEvent (app.js?_dc=1481916938387:56438)
```

Comment: Could you please share me the sample code for exporting using the dropdown @aMazing ??

Comment: Sorry @Coded9 i dont have access to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `requires`.

If you tell ExtJS to use `type:'csv'`, it will try to instantiate `exporter.csv`. If you tell ExtJS to use `type:'excel'`, it will try to instantiate `exporter.excel`. To get that one from the file system, you have to include the fully qualified name somewhere, e.g. in your `requires` section:

```
requires:[
    'Ext.exporter.text.CSV'
]
```

The heading in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.exporter.text.CSV.html) has two parts: First the full qualified class name, which is "Ext.exporter.text.CSV", and then, the short name ("exporter.csv"). If you haven't provided the full name anywhere, the file cannot be loaded, unless the framework itself already requires the exporter by full name. Which it, according to the error message, doesn't.

Background info, before you ask "Why doesn't it?": Since the plugin can work with any of the dozens of exporters, and you wouldn't want to load all just to create one type of export, you have to import the exporter manually.

Comment: Adding the requires fixed the problem. However can you please clarify what you mean by import the exporter manually, I wouldnt know how to do that manually using SA.

Comment: @aMazing The `requires` part does just that.

Comment: right. so in my case, I will have to add requires for all types that are being used to the project to SA. Also do you know from the top of your head if Exporter supports PDF? or anyway i could make it support pdf

Comment: where can I get the controller: grid-exporter code mentioned in the kitchen sink example ?@Alexander

Comment: @Coded9 Don't know, you may want to ask Sencha that question.